# Implementing provider pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, database-design, data-access-layer

I have seen some articles on provider patten. I have a little idea of it and its benefit.  I tried to see and do its implementation but got confused. Different authors have done it in different ways. I am very confused on how to do it. Some were using framework 1.1 but I am using 3.5 framework.

Please guide me or refer me some links on its **easy and step by step** implementation.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Miguel Castro's excellent webcast on the topic:

[Writing provider-based features in ASP.NET](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=89)

Watch it - internalize it - live it - it's a really great intro!